# How to initiate a function including AJAX request some time after the user's last input?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is the crucial code:

```
var ajaxCallTimeoutID = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("input[id^='question']").live('keyup',function(ev){
    id=this.id.substr(8);
    if (ajaxCallTimeoutID != null)
    clearTimeout(ajaxCallTimeoutID);
ajaxCallTimeoutID = setTimeout(subjectivecheck(id), 1000);

}); 
});
```

However,

> subjectivecheck(id)
>   is immediately executed when a user inputs a letter, but I hope it is called after the user has stopped typing for a specified amount of time. How to solve this problem?

```
function subjectivecheck(id){
    var cost=(new Date().getTime() - start.getTime())/1000;
    var value=$('#question'+id).val();
    $.post("subjectivecheck.php?",{val:value, qid:id,time:cost, a_id:"<?php echo $announcementid; ?>"},function(xm){

        switch(parseInt(xm)){
            case 4:
            { $htm='Congrats,you have passed the test.';
                $('#success').css({"color":"green"});
                $('#success').text($htm);
            return; 
            }
            case 1:
            {
            $htm='V';
        $('#sign'+id).css({"color":"green"});
        $('#sign'+id).text($htm);
        break;  
            }
            case 0:{

                 $htm='X';
        $('#sign'+id).css({"color":"red"});
        $('#sign'+id).text($htm);
        break;
            }
            case 3:{
                $('#subjectivequestion').text('You have failed at this announcement.');

                $('#choicequestions').text(" ");
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
ajaxCallTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){subjectivecheck(id)}, 1000);
```

Without the wrapped `function(){}` the function `subjectivecheck` gets called immediately, but when you wrap it you pass a reference to the function as an argument. Later that function can be called, which will then call your function.

Comment: subjectivecheck(id) is never called when I wrap it in an anonymous function as you said.

Comment: It doesn't work.ajaxCallTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){subjectivecheck(id)}, 1000);
does not work.

Comment: I tested with alert instead of subjectivecheck, and that works. The problem has to do with subjectivecheck, not the code you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is start the timeout on keyup, and clear the timeout on keydown (or keypress).

```
var timers=[];
$('input[id^="question"]').keydown(function(){
  while(timers.length){
    clearTimeout(timers.shift());
  }
}).keyup(function(){
  var timeout=setTimeout(function(){
    //ajax call here
  }, 300);
  timers.push(timeout);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it must be $("input[id^='question']").live() since the corresponding code is dynamically created.

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to change the above code to `live('keydown')`